# How to hide add to cart button in Woocommerce using AJAX IF items already in the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need some help, i have this snippet in wordpress:

```
    add_action('wp_head', function (){ 
?>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        // Customer click = hide button
        $(".products, .add_to_cart_inline, .added").on("click", function(e) {
            $(".add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple").hide();
        });

        });
    </script>

<?php });
```

This code is hiding **all** add to cart button after user clicked it.

**My goal:** For every item/product that has been added to the cart, the add to cart button is automatically hidden.

Here is a screenshot for what i want to achieve:

[Button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDwYy.png)

[Button hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6e4V.png)

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is selecting all the buttons.
You have to select only the button that is being clicked and hide it.

Try this script instead. It uses `$(this)` to select the button clicked.
Make sure you are selecting the correct button class. Use devtools, for example, to see what class every add button has in common.

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
  // Customer click = hide button
    $(".add_to_cart_button").on("click", function(e) {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times @Azametsin
This is working, i use .add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple for it to work.

Well i should really study my java a lot more. Thank you again!